# Magic in C with malloc, fork and open

Tags: c, file-io, malloc, fork

I have such a funny problem I thought I'd share with you.

I cornered it down to the most little program I could :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int cmd_left(char *name)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int   f_d;

  if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
      perror("");
      exit(1);
    }
  f_d = open(name);
  printf("%d\n", f_d);
  close(f_d);
}

int main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
{
  char **dummy_env;

  if (ac < 2)
    return (0);
  dummy_env = malloc(10);
  cmd_left(av[1]);
}
```

Basically, if I remove the malloc, opening works just fine.
You just have to compile and give the program a (valid) file to see the magic.

Comment: Dont you mean `malloc(10 * sizeof(char*))` ?

Comment: Nope, I just wanted the most little thing possible

Comment: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘open’

Comment: Thank yi_H, solves the problem, facepalm for me (open takes two arguments)

Comment: @Joe: `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you should always compile with -Wall

Comment: Thanks @JerryCoffin but i think I said `sizeof(char*)` emphasis on `*`.

Comment: @Joe: Good point -- I should have read more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `#include <fcntl.h>` to get a declaration for `open()` in scope, which would then tell you that you are not calling it with enough arguments:

```
int open(const char *filename, int flags, ...);
```

(The optional argument - singular - is the permissions for the file (`mode_t perms`) if you have `O_CREAT` amongst the options in the `flags` argument.)

The call to `malloc()` scribbles over enough stack to remove the zeroes on it initially, which leaves the 'extra arguments' to `open()` in a state where they are not zero and you run into problems.

Undefined behaviour - which you're invoking - can lead to any weird result.

Make sure you compile with at least '`gcc -Wall`' and I recommend '`gcc -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wall -Wextra`'.

Answer (score 4):

`open(2)` takes at least two parameters. Since you are passing it only one argument, you are invoking Undefined Behavior. In this case, `open()` is just using some garbage as second argument.

Comment: @user1078262: Click in the check-mark shape below the current score for the answer. When you do, it'll turn green signaling that you've accepted the answer.

Comment: Actually, I think this makes for a perfect example of the dangers of UB. No need for nasal demons, just think of O_TRUNC.

Answer (score 1):

The header file for `open` is missing and open expects at least a second parameter.

If you fix that it should be OK.